# how to event handeler using google translater API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I am using google translator api that it's allow me and give just small piece of code to add on your website and it will show dropdown that u can change any language so is it any pattern or some that on this drop down i can attach my event whenever has changed any language i can perform my logic thanks.

I want simply then when ever i changed language from drop down i want to perform some action.

here is code

```html
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE }, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>
```

here is an image of drop down that after adding this code it's showing me.

[Drop down Translater Image want to bind my event when any language select any event that allow me to do this please tell me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke039.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could detect whenever somebody clicks on `#google_translate_element` but methods to trigger a function when user click a language button, would be considered 'hacky' and may fail whenever Google updates it scripts.

To handle clicks with jquery, you could use something like:

```
$( "#google_translate_element" ).click(function() {
alert( "Clicked on Translate!" );
});
```

Comment: but problem is that if i will apply on this ID as u mentioned so it will trigger before selecting any language and want when user click any specific anchor tag not on div so if user click on div so before language selection it will be trigger it wil be useless for me. i hopu can understand

Comment: I get your point but unless you have an API defined for that purpose, there would be no reliable way to do that. Anything you may do would probably be a hack.